# Examples of scientific progress revolutionizing philosophic thought?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, metaphilosophy

The role of paradigm shifts in understanding is often discussed in the context of scientific progress. What are some prime examples of scientific progress initiating paradigm shifts in religion/philosophy? These by nature are more tradition bound and thus slower moving, and "yet they move"... For example, one that comes to my mind is the effect of Darwin's theories on Christian thought. The more recent, the better.

Thanks!

Comment: Modern neuroscience combined with evolutionary psychology have some "interesting" things to say about awareness, consciousness and free will... See Gazzaniga "Who's In Charge?" for instance or Robert Wright's "The Moral Animal".  I don't know how much of an effect this research has had on philosophy, it's probably too early (30-40 years) to have had much of an impact.

Comment: Darwin may be an example but it's difficult to think of others. QM should have caused a paradigm-shift but seems to have had no effect at all. Jim suggests work in neuroscience and phil.of mind as an example but I can't see that this had changed anything. We'll need at least one major paradigm-shift if philosophy is ever to catch up with physics. Perhaps the hopelessness of the 'hard' problem will lead to one as Chalmers' recent writings might indicate. My suspicion is that academic philosophy has too great an inertia to undergo a paradigm-shift.

Answer (score 1):

1. Newtonian Mechanics on Kant.
2. Quantum mechanics, specifically the measurement problem, on
   modern philosophy's concept of ontology and epistemology.
3. Computer science on philosophy of mind.

Just to name a few.